# Why won't a div with a scrollbar drag in IE 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a div with the following rules:

```
div#eventBox
{
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px inset #888;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    background-color: #1a5c17;
    background-image: url("/Images/Background_Images/GrungePaper.jpg");
    behavior: url(/Resources/PIE.htc);
}
```

Everything works perfectly in it, except for in IE 8 (tests fine in IE 9). In IE 8 when I try to "click and drag" the scrollbar, it immediately becomes "unclicked" just after mousedown, preventing any IE users on 32-bit machines from using this scrollbar feature. Everything else about the scrollbar works fine, like clicking the arrows, clicking the space between an arrow and the scrollbar, and using the mousewheel.

I have tried removing the `behavior: url(/Resources/PIE.htc);` rule, but the problem persists.

Do div's with overflow auto not work/have bugs in IE 8?

Also, this has been tested in 32-bit and 64-bit versions of FF and Chrome, and everything works fine there, too.

**Update:**

I have tested this consistently and I can't seem to figure out what's going on, nor can I see any examples of this ever happening to anyone else online. I tested it with the only rule for `div#eventBox` being `overflow: auto;`, `overflow: scroll;`, `overflow-y: auto;`, and/or `overflow-y: scroll;` and the problem STILL persists. Every time I click the scrollbar in IE 8 (no compatibility mode) it loses focus.

I find it as hard to believe that this is a known bug (because of the zero relevant search results) as it is to believe that this is something I have messed up, since all it takes is one div with overflowing content producing a scrollbar to cause this glitch.

If I was a rich man, back when Internet Explorer 8 was being developed, I would have gladly paid for everyone from Microsoft's Internet Explorer Project Team to take a class on "best practices" and "adhering to standards".

**Update 2:**

Actually if I double-click the scrollbar really fast and hold down the second click, I can actually get a hold of it in IE 8. Of course, this is still no good from an end-user perspective, but perhaps that behavior will help explain the cause.

**Final Update (Solution):**

From the advice I received from the comments to this post, I decided to remove all script and CSS and start adding things back in, one at a time. The error wasn't in any script, but in CSS. For whatever reason the `behavior: url(/Resources/PIE.htc);` set on the main site wrapper div (Far up the DOM tree from the problem element) was apparently causing the problem. I still don't know how, but the solution for me was to simply remove PIE from that element, which in turn broke the other two PIE references, which I was able to fix by setting their position to relative. For now, everything seems to work fine in IE 8, but the moment I experience any other problems as a result of using PIE, I will purge it from my site.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript on the page that intercepts mouseDown or click events?

Comment: @SetSailMedia Yes, Sir, I do

Comment: @SetSailMedia I have several `$("#elementID").click(function(){//do stuff here });` jQuery event handlers, to be specific.

Comment: Where's the 'dragin n dropin' code ? I (WE) need a 'live' example to figure out what is causing your situation.

Comment: @MilchePatern There is no 'dragin n dropin' code. It's IE's inherent scrollbar that won't drag.

Comment: @MilchePatern I'm happy to supply any code necessary, but there is a lot of it. Considering I don't know what is causing the issue, I would have to post all of it and there are, currently 714 lines of code.

Comment: Actually if I double-click the scrollbar really fast and hold down the second click, I can actually get a hold of it in IE 8. Of course, this is still no good from an end-user percpective, but perhaps that behavior will help explain the cause.

Comment: You might try removing all of your event handlers, to see if it resolves the issue? They should not be affecting the scrollbar, rather the element itself, but as you alluded to, IE developers are not the sharpest in the tool shed.

Comment: @SetSailMedia LOL, right after I tried that very thing I came back to your comment suggesting that I do, just that. "HOW" I did that was by adding `$("*").off("click");` to my code just after the content of the div is filled (and thus causing the scrollbar to show up). It indeed shuts off all click events on the page, but the issue, still persists. Is there any way of handling this? It is for a public website, so it has to be fully compatible with IE 8.

Comment: Is the bug reproduced at http://jsfiddle.net/X6kfD/? If that page works then it is some other code affecting that is causing it. Start adding your JavaScript piece by piece to narrow down the cause.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Unfortunately jsfiddle refuses to be displayed or function correctly when I visit it on the IE 8 machines we have.

Comment: @VoidKing then make a new page, isolate only the code you posted (HTML + CSS) and see if that works. Slowly add functionality until it breaks again and you'll know what's causing it.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Okay, sounds like good advice to me. I will try that, thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Okay, your advice did the trick, and I guess I should've known, but it was the `behavior` set to PIE on the main div wrapper (an element far up the DOM tree from the problem element). Unfortunately I don't see a way to preserve it, and I believe that this is a sign that using the PIE project is bad practice. Jesus, I wish Microsoft would get off their ass and make a CSS3 compatible browser for 32-bit machines, like EVERY other browser developer. But I don't see that happening. Thanks for the help, and if you post as an answer I will be happy to accept.

Comment: @VoidKing Personally I would just follow the progressive enhancement route and not use PIE for older browsers. It slows down their performance and causes issues for relatively little gain. Users of those browsers are used to less than perfect pages.

Comment: Check your Z-Index level